# Why does maven 3.2 download same artifact multiple times from all repositories defined in pom

Tags: maven-3, dependency-management, repository

I have defined 2 repositories in pom.xml like below. One is public and other is thirdparty.

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
        <id>public</id>
        <name>Nexus - Public Repositories</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://mavenrepo.aaa.net/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>       
    <repository>
        <id>thirdparty</id>
        <name>Nexus - Third Party</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://mavenrepo.aaa.net/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>       
</repositories>
```

Say there is a dependency called grpId:artId:1.1.0 which I have defined in my pom. This dependency is present in both the repositories defined above- public and thirdparty

When I run mvn install I see different behaviours in the way maven downloads the grpId:artId:1.1.0 artifact based on the version of maven i am using.

Behaviours :-

**1. Using Maven 3.1 and previous versions**

- **a.** Maven looks up the dependency grpId:artId:1.1.0 in 'public' repo
- **b.** Maven finds the dependency and downloads it.
- **c.** Maven does not look up the dependency grpId:artId:1.1.0 in
  'thirdparty' repo as it is already downloaded from previous repository.

**2. Using Maven 3.2**

- **a.** Maven looks up the dependency grpId:artId:1.1.0 in 'public' repo
- **b.** Maven finds the dependency in 'public' repo and downloads it.
- **c.** Maven again looks up the dependency grpId:artId:1.1.0 in
  'thirdparty' repo even  though it is already downloaded from 'public' repository.
- **d.** Maven finds the dependency in 'thirdparty' repo and downloads it
  and overwrites the dependency downloaded from 'public' repo previously

I wonder why maven is behaving in an absurd manner for maven-3.2. It should stop looking further for the dependency which is already resolved and downloaded from one repository .

Is there a way to achieve it using maven 3.2 ?

Comment: Why do you have `<updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>`?

Comment: updatePolicy is just to look for the updated metadata and update the artifact accordingly, but we can remove it. That's not a problem

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug identified and fixed by maven in version 3.2.5

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5723